# How to correctly formalize the command line usage of GNU/Linux commands?

Tags: grammar, bnf

I'd like to write down a BNF-like formal grammar for describing the command line usage of some GNU/Linux tools. For example I can describe the usage of the `cat` command as:

```
(cat-command) : 'cat' (arguments-list)
(arguments-list) : (argument)
(arguments-list) : (arguments-list) (argument)
(argument) : (file)
```

The problem is I can't write down a precise grammar for some commands such as `md5sum`. My first attempt at that would be the following:

```
(md5sum-command) : 'md5sum' (arguments-list)
(arguments-list) : (argument)
(arguments-list) : (arguments-list) (argument)
(argument) : (file)
(argument) : '--check'
```

But as you can see this grammar allows you to specify the `--check` argument as many times as you wish, which is incorrect as you should use it at most one time.

How can I fix that? Also, what kind of formal grammars I should study for better treating this kind of problems?

Comment: Are you sure that your grammar IS incorrect ?  For me many of the Unix commands quite happily accept multiple occurrences of the same argument, eg 'ls -l -l -l'.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But maybe there are some tools that don't allow repetitions. I may also write my own program that doesn't allow repetitions. So I think my problem is still relevant.

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like:

```
(md5sum-command) : 'md5sum' (arguments-list)
(arguments-list) : (file-arguments) | '--check' (file-arguments)
(file-arguments) : (file) (file-arguments)
```

Assuming you want to be able to specify exactly one `--check` per command, but not depend on it being the first argument, you could use:

```
(md5sum-command) : 'md5sum' (arguments-list)
(arguments-list) : (file-arguments) | (file-arguments) '--check' (file-arguments)
(file-arguments) : (file) (file-arguments)
```

Also note, that the pipe (`|`) symbol is just a shortcut for an additional rule. The following is equivalent:

```
(md5sum-command) : 'md5sum' (arguments-list)
(arguments-list) : (file-arguments) 
(arguments-list) : (file-arguments) '--check' (file-arguments)
(file-arguments) : (file) (file-arguments)
```

I'd be surprised if you couldn't specify most unix commands with a context free grammar like those expressed in BNFs.

Comment: Your version seems to work, but it is not general enough. For example, you are not required to put the '--check' argument immediately after the 'md5sum' argument: you can have many files specified before and after it.

Comment: Having read your new version, I managed to write down the following:
(arguments-list) : [(files-list)] [(mode-option)] [(files-list)] ['--check'] [(files-list)]
(arguments-list) : [(files-list)] ['--check'] [(files-list)] [(mode-option)] [(files-list)]
(mode-option) : '--binary'
(mode-option) : '--text'
I couldn't abbreviate it further. So adding other arguments such as '--quiet', '--warn' or '--status' would result in an exceedingly long grammar for such a simple command.

Comment: True. You probably want to make a difference between arguments that are just flags (can appear anywhere in argument list, act globally) and arguments that act on the files following.

Answer (score -1):

I probably found an answer, although it's not the expected one. You can choose to recognise the correctness of a command instead of generate correct commands. Using some hybrid language, you can write the following set of requirements:

```
argument(0) == "md5sum"
forall i, if i != 0 then argument(i) == "--binary" or
                         argument(i) == "--text" or
                         argument(i) == "--check" or
                         argument(i) == "--status" or
                         argument(i) belongs to <file>
0 <= instances("--binary") + instances("--text") <= 1
0 <= instances("--check") <= 1
if instances("--check") == 1 then 0 <= instances("--status") <= 1
```

I won't mark this answer as the correct one because I'm still curious to know if there exists a way to *generate* correct commands.